# Where to download the latest version of the react-transition group dependency?

Tags: reactjs

In my reactjs project I currently have react-transition-group: 1.2.1. I need to upgrade however  [after using this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-transition-group)

and running it in the terminal the transition group stays the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: I hope you use some dependency management tool. Maybe `npm` or `yarn`. Downloading package manually is really rare nowadays. After checking what tool is used you better check its docs for "update dependency" section

Comment: What command are you running in the console?

Comment: I am using a dependency management tool it's npm. This is the command: npm i react-transition-group. Refrenced from here [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-transition-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use semantic version

1. For Patch releases use **~**
2. For Minor releases use **^**
3. For Major releases: * or x

Please refer this link for more details - https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

As current version of react-transition-group is 4.1.1,to update use below command

```
npm install react-transition-group@4.1.1 --save
```

Best option is to update package.json as below (Use **^**, **~**, * based on your dependency requirement)

```
react-transition-group: "^4.1.1"
```

Comment: after you run the command do you type the new number 4.1.1 in replacement of the old or does it do that automatically

Comment: Because after running this command and refreshing my ide it still says react-transitiongroup: 1.2.1, despite the command fixing all my errors

Comment: @JavaHava, if you want to save globally use -g as well, I think your package.json have 1.2.1 version

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help I'm verifying your answer